# PHP Class not found but it's in folder and it is also included

Tags: php, file, class, include

I'v a singular proble... if I include files in this manner:

```
<?php     
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
    foreach (glob("../class/*.php") as $filename)
    {
        echo "$filename\n";
        include $filename;
    }
    foreach (glob("../utilities/*.php") as $filename) {
        echo "$filename\n";
        include $filename;
    }

class ECommerce {
    private $checker;
    private $errorManager;

    /**
     * ECommerce constructor.
     */
    function __construct() {
        $this->checker = new Checker();
        $this->errorManager = new ErrorManager();
    }
```

the website doesn't work and when I do

```
$ecommerce = new ECommerce();
```

it says that

> Class 'ErrorManager' not found in path

I thought anything, when I'v thought to try this:

```
 <?php     
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
    include "../class/Checker.php";
    include "../class/User.php";
    include "../utilities/ErrorManager.php";

class ECommerce {
    private $checker;
    private $errorManager;

    /**
     * ECommerce constructor.
     */
    function __construct() {
        $this->checker = new Checker();
        $this->errorManager = new ErrorManager();
    }
```

in this manner, it works and anything does what it has to do!
Inside me, the question "why", has made roots and I can't sleep (really).
Why first manner works for all classes except for ErrorManager?
Thank you before!

Here, there is ErrorManager class code (it has the blank construct like Checker class)

```
<?php
class ErrorManager
{
function __construct() {
}

function getErrorUserNameNotValid() {
    return "Nome inserito non valido";
}

function getErrorUserSurnameNotValid() {
    return "Cognome inserito non valido";
}

function getErrorUserEmailAlreadyExists() {
    return "Email inserita non valida!";
}

function getErrorUserEmailNotValid() {
    return "Email inserita non valida!";
}

function getErrorUserPasswordNotValid() {
    return "Password inserita non valida! Inserisci una password che sia lunga tra i 6 e i 50 caratteri!";
}

function getErrorUserAddressNotValid() {
    return "Indirizzo inserito non valido!";
}

function getErrorUserPhoneNumberNotValid() {
    return "Numero telefonico inserito non valido! Inserisci solo numeri, senza trattini o caratteri speciali!";
}
}
```

I include a screenshot of folder too
[image]

I'm trying this now, with AutoLoader:
This is in ECommerce class:

```
spl_autoload_register('MyAutoloader::ClassLoader');
spl_autoload_register('MyAutoloader::LibraryLoader');
```

And this is in MyAutoloaderClass

```
class MyAutoloader
{
public static function ClassLoader($className)
{
    $path = "../class/";
    include $path.$className.'.php';
}


public static function LibraryLoader($className)
{

    $path = __DIR__."/";
    include $path.$className.'.php';
}
```

}

It says that

> include(../class/ErrorManager.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: @Brett of course, it's coming!

Comment: ../utilities/ErrorManager.php and are you sure that's the correct path. The utilities folder is in the same folder as the classes folder?

Comment: @Brett yes! If I include with a foreach loop it doesn't work, with manual path yes >_>

Comment: What does the echo say for the 2nd loop? Does it match that of the manual input?

Comment: @Brett Nope, it shows only "../utilities/Dispatcher.php" as class, it doesn't show "../utilities/ErrorManager.php"!

Comment: @Brett Done! Thank you for your time, however :)

Comment: This is very strange. I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't be displaying. Is there a permissions issue? Are you on windows?

Comment: @Brett I'm on windows, but I'm trying it also on a Linux Server that hosts my webspace!

Comment: See the last edit. There might be a dependency in Dispatcher getting loaded before ErrorHandler. I strongly recommend to use a class loader as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I've solved changing "include" in "require_once". If u know why this solve the problem, I would read you happily! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: `require_once` or `include_once` prevent includes of the same file multiple times. `require` throws an error when the file does not exist. The message "Class 'ErrorManager' not found in path" is uncommon on multiple includes. The expected error message is: "Fatal error: Cannot declare class <name>, because the name is already in use in <filename> on line #". `require_once` can help in unstructured projects. Auto class loaders should be the way to go. Then `require` satisfies and safes some performance eaten by a class loader on the other hand.

Comment: I'v added autoloader and it looks for ErrorManager in Class path instead Utilities. Looks more details in my question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: It's up to you to handle class load requests in an autoloader callback. You can even register more than one spl-autoload functions, e.g. each one declared in a file inside classes and utilities folder. If you have difficulties with spl-autoload, I suggest you to create a new question about it (if you can not find applicable answers already handled on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include` on a relative path will search the file based on the path of the called PHP script, not the included PHP file your are calling include from.

To be able to include even if your ECommerce class is used from different locations, try

```
include __DIR__ . '/' . $filename;
```

On older PHP versions you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__`.

There might be other dependencies before `ErrorManager.php` gets loaded, e.g. in `Dispatcher.php`.

What happens if you test the following?

```
include "../class/Checker.php";
include "../class/User.php";
include "../utilities/Dispatcher.php";
include "../utilities/ErrorManager.php";
```

Consider to use a class loading mechanism like [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). It makes the class dependency management much easier.

Comment: So why Checker has been included well?

Comment: I'v seen the edit. My problem is in foreach loop, the manual include works!

Comment: I've first finished the edit to be more general. If other classes have been successfully included before, then there might be a dependency in other classes earlier, before ErrorManager gets loaded. There could even be an autoload/spl_autoload mechanism.

Comment: It still gives me error on ErrorManager class... I'm desperate!

Comment: Open your error log file. What is the full log of one request?

Comment: I don't think it could be husefull, however this is it: 2016-06-01 04:44:20,368 [62675159]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - ApplicationImpl.externalInstanceListener invocation 
2016-06-01 04:44:20,368 [62675159]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - External command line: 
2016-06-01 04:44:20,368 [62675159]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - Dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2016.1.1\jre\jre\bin\. 
2016-06-01 04:44:20,368 [62675159]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - C:\Users\danie\.PhpStorm2016.1\system\log\idea.log

Comment: Looks like an application debug log. Do you run PHP on jetbrain's integrated webserver? Doesn't it provide a separate error.log on web requests?

Comment: I'll see your link. However now I've solved all changing "include" in "require_once". If u know why this solve the problem, I would read you happily! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: P.s. As I said in my question, testing manual path like "include ../path" worked!

Comment: P.s. As I mentioned in the answer, I advised manual testing of include of *Dispatcher before ErrorManager*. ;-)

Comment: If I include Dispatcher before then ErrorManager it gives me error! But in Dispatcher I don't user ErrorMaanger!